# Get/change Icon of an exe file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

There is an application called Resource Hacker which modifies the icon of an exe file but is there any library that does this in Python? If not, do you have any suggestions on how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean while compiling the exe (written in python) ?

Comment: @Joshua No, I mean taking the content of any compiled exe file and getting the hex of its icon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use python. This will save the icon to "save_location" variable. You can then import it and do what you want with it.

Python code:

```
import os

path_to_exe = r"C:\Users\Dtomper\Desktop\test.exe"
save_location = r"C:\Users\Dtomper\Photos"
library_location = r"C:\Users\Dtomper\Downloads\IconsExtract"

os.chdir(library_location)
os.system('iconsext.exe /save "'+path_to_exe+'" "'+save_location+'" -icons')
```

You just have to download this tool to work with the above code: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html

Comment: Thank you, that works with extracting icons, now I only want to know how to change them.

Comment: @Dtomper there is a way to change it but you must encapsulate the existing exe with your own custom python exe. you can decide the icon for your own custom python exe, which will encapsulate the original exe......... encapsulate meaning ur new python exe will contain the old exe inside itself.